# jquery set data attr

Tags: jquery

**Html**

```
<div id="you" data-you="Hello mean">super</div>
```

is #you html element change data-you attribute

```
console.log($("#you").data("you")); // Hello mean

$("#you").attr("data-you", "yes change you atribute");

console.log($("#you").data("you")); // Hello mean | does not change.
```

Attribute  "data-you" does not change when I change. How can I do this?

thank you.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

attr() And you can not have to change the data() method.

Try the following way:

```
console.log($("#you").data("you")); // Hello mean

$("#you").data("you", "yes change you atribute"); // yes change you atribute

console.log($("#you").data("you")); //  yes change you atribute
```

examples of data
http://api.jquery.com/data/​​​​​​

Comment: if anyone finds the first line of the above answer confusing, please check my answer below.

Answer (score 88):

There has already been an answer chosen as a correct one, however its seems
like none of the answers clearly and concisely explain what is happening.
So let me give this a shot:

`$(element).data(key, value)` **does not** change the html5 'data-*' attributes of the element, jQuery internally stores the key-value (in jQuery.cache).
As a result when you call `$(element).data(key)` you get what is stored internally by jQuery.

To answer your question here:

Since you are looking to change the `data-you` attribute of your html tag  you will instead need to use the `attr()` method

Thus:

```
console.log($("#you").attr("data-you")); // Hello mean

$("#you").attr("data-you", "yes change you atribute");

console.log($("#you").attr("data-you")); // The data-you attribute has been changed.
```

Comment: In case anyone is interested, the ability to access HTML5 `data-` attributes was added in jQuery version 1.4.3. Prior to that it was only for internal data storage associated with an element, and really it's still for internal data storage, with the new feature that you can initially load some data with an HTML5 `data-` attribute.

Comment: Your code snippet is exactly the same as the one in the question, except that you claim the data-you attribute has been changed. When I do this, the attribute has not been changed. Did you mean to use the snippet from Yaşar İÇLİ's answer?

Comment: the code snippet contains `attr` instead of `data` which is not the case in the code given by the others. please check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NneCY/ and observe the console logs. thankyou.

Comment: this fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Bf7Mz/ shows that the answer by Yaşar İÇLİ' is unfortunately incorrect.

Comment: Your fiddle for Yaşar's answer does not match the code in his answer! Proof that his answer works: [jsfiddle.net/J2mzS](http://jsfiddle.net/J2mzS/)

Comment: `console.log($("#you").attr("data-you"));` was inserted in the last line to show that the attribute **hasn't** changed. please try understanding Gerbus, with the `.data` method one is NOT changing the attribute but instead the internal storage in jquery of the element. however the question and Yaşar İÇLİ's answers are referring to the element's *attribute*. finally check this jsfiddle.net/J2mzS/1 for understanding how Yasar's solution isn't actually changing the attribute.

Comment: @Gerbus I do not mind your downvote... but atleast please don't spread around misconceptions about the way `data` works. this question already had an accepted answer 6 months before i happened to stumble upon it. i posted an answer to help the readers of this question to obtain the correct information about the problem. you've misread the code snippet i gave and not understanding the issue. please stop this gerbus.

Comment: +1 The only answer that is correct and full in explanation - should be the accepted answer. So much confusion still caused by the fact that jQuery data() and HTML 'data-xyz' are two completely different methods of storing data - as apparent from the comments.

Answer (score 2):

On your same logic, to see the result; change `data` to `attr`

```
console.log($("#you").attr("data-you"));
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/asCVU/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("#you").data("you", "yes change you atribute");
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$("#you").attr("data-you","New Value");
```

Comment: please explain why this snippet solves the problem, and have a look at [answer].