# Cannot set data-id to HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm searching for this sometime. Found this [old article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507718/why-dont-changes-to-jquery-fn-data-update-the-corresponding-html-5-data-a/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872176/jquery-set-data-attr). But not working for me.

My Problem is : I cannot set incremented `data-id` to HTML Element via jQuery. I'm able to alert the same, But I failed to set in HTML. There is no change in the element if I inspect.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
   $("#search").click(function(){      
   var num = $(this).data('id');    
    num++; 
    $("span").text(num);
    $(this).data('id', num);
   });    
 });
```

I tried this also

```
$(this).data('id') === num;
```

Here is a **[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/JU4H4/9/)**

I'm using `v1.9.1` and no error in console. Its great if anyone can find the issue.

Comment: Notice that the jQuery `data` method does not set data attributes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All other answers are correct - fixing `'val'` to `val` - that of course solves the `NaN` issue.

The problem however is:

> I cannot set incremented data-id to HTML Element via jQuery. I'm able
>   to alert the same, But I failed to set in HTML. There is no change in
>   the element if I inspect.

jQuery uses internal representation (1) for `data`. If you want to see `data-id` in inspector you need to use:
`$(this).attr('data-id', num);`

---

(1) "Internal represenation":

> All data is stored inside a property of the jQuery object named cache.
>   Log the contents of $.cache in your console to see all data and events
>   associated with any DOM element.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4385015/775359

Comment: I will stick with `.attr`. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line.

```
$(this).data('id', 'num');
```

num should be a variable, not a string.

Change it to this and it will work fine:

```
$(this).data('id', num);
```

Comment: Sorry that was a Typo, Not Working with variable too

Comment: Your fiddle works for me. When you click the div, the number is increased. What is it that you are expecting?

Comment: I cannot set incremented data-id to HTML Element. See yourself by inspecting.

Comment: But you evidently can, otherwise the number in the span would not increase. If you are expecting to see the data attribute updated on the element, see here for why that won't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384784/jquery-data-storage/4385015#4385015

Answer (score 2):

Try this to get:

```
$(this).attr('data-id');
```

and this to set attribue:

```
$(this).attr('data-id', num);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Standard Pure Javascript data-attr**

try this

```
this.dataset['id']=num;
```

or

```
this.dataset.id=num;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JU4H4/8/

**EDIT**
based on the comments and also why i don't use jaquery

here is a partial function for data-attr taken from jquery's code.(i don't use jquery)

```
function dataAttr( elem, key, data ) {
        var name;

        // If nothing was found internally, try to fetch any
        // data from the HTML5 data-* attribute
        if ( data === undefined && elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
                name = "data-" + key.replace( rmultiDash, "-$1" ).toLowerCase();
                data = elem.getAttribute( name );

                if ( typeof data === "string" ) {
                        try {
                                data = data === "true" ? true :
                                        data === "false" ? false :
                                        data === "null" ? null :
                                        // Only convert to a number if it doesn't change the string
                                        +data + "" === data ? +data :
                                        rbrace.test( data ) ? jQuery.parseJSON( data ) :
                                        data;
                        } catch( e ) {}

                        // Make sure we set the data so it isn't changed later
                        data_user.set( elem, key, data );
                } else {
                        data = undefined;
                }
        }
        return data;
}
```

Comment: There is no `dataset` property on jQuery collections?

Comment: it's javascript. and it sets the data-attr

Comment: Of course jQuery is JavaScript, but there is no `dataset` in jQuery. Did you mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.dataset?

Comment: yeah is that different?

Comment: yeah jquery does not point to the real this with $(this)... i didn't know that. you know .. i don't use jquery.

Comment: but it's the same. and as it's a standard... it's 100% better to use dataset vs data(bla,bla)

Comment: Actually jQuery's `data` method does not even set the data attributes (nor the `dataset` store), it only retrieves it.

Comment: @cocco Your solution is working. But can I include `js` inside Jquery?

Comment: jquery is a mix of js functions. so yes. you should first learn js then to make your scripts more compatible with ie6 use jquery

Comment: jquery is only here to make some scripts work with internet explorer 6, because almost all browsers and phones have standards now.so jquery is no needed anymore... but apparently ppl don't know that.

Comment: @cocco I wonder why jquery don't have this function :-( How about Zub's answer?

Comment: this is a new standard in javascript 1.7. it works on all modern browsers.if you prefer Zub's jquery solution use that...

Answer (score -1):

Use the variable `num`, not the string `'num'`:

```
$(this).data('id', num);
```

[Updated jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JU4H4/2/)

Comment: Sorry that was a Typo, Your fiddle is also not working. The data-id is not set to that element (Please see it by inspecting)

Comment: @SurjithSM: Why would you need that? Of course you could simply use `this.dataset.id = num;` or `$(this).attr("data-id", num)` or `$(this).prop("dataset").id = num`, but why not use the internal datastore provided by jQuery that is working in all browsers?

Comment: `.prop("dataset")` is also working.. But I will stick on to `attr` now